# Migrated MS SQL Databases

Tags: sql-server

I have a production database of 700 GB to migrate, I want to reduce downtime to practically nothing.  We could take a backup and restore from that but the downtime would be 4+ hours.

Can I do transaction log shipping?  THis is SQL Server 2017 Enterprise edition.

Comment: Start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/migrate/?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Are you migrating between the same versions and editions of SQL Server between your two instances?

Comment: @J.D. Hi yes we are!

Answer (score 2):

> Can I do transaction log shipping?

So long as the databases are in FULL recovery mode, yes see [Fail Over to a Log Shipping Secondary (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/log-shipping/fail-over-to-a-log-shipping-secondary-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

But since you're on SQL 2017 you can also use a [cluster-less read-scale Availability Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/read-scale-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver15#read-scale-availability-groups-without-cluster) to create a replica and then fail over.  This would have the absolute minimum failover time.

Comment: We ended up doing transaction log shipping as it is simple to configure and we are going to stand up the new database and sunset the old one.

Answer (score 0):

For this operation it would be easier to configure database mirroring, you will be sure that everything is migrated. Here is the link how to configure mirroring:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/database-mirroring/database-mirroring-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Also of you can have some down time you could do backup/restore of full backup with no recovery, stop the application and take differential backup/restore. Downtime will be shorter than 4h.